# Implement a decimal from a String into a Stack

Tags: java, eclipse, stack, decimal

I'm coding a calculator with a GUI in Java. I read out the string and save the numbers and operations into 2 stacks. My problem is: How can I read out decimals like 5.6 or 5.625 and save them into 1 stack?

thanks for help

Joe

Comment: You mean how to parse a string into a Double or BigDecimal?

Comment: @eckes : No. I read out number by number and save them into a stack. Example: 5 + 5  operation.stack: [+] number.stack: [5],[5]. Thats working without problems, but when I use this example : 5.25 + 2 operation.stack: [+] number.stack: [5],[2],[5],[2].

Comment: Show us the code.

Comment: Well, you need to tell us which step you have problems with, what types do you put onto that stack and how you generate them. It sounds like you parse integers instead of doubles. Or maybe you use the wrong pattern/tokenizer.

Comment: Yeah I´m sorry, but i solved my Problem. I´ll heed your advice for the next time.@eckes

Answer (score -2, accepted):

deleted the content deleted the content